# Funny Plumbing sound

Tags: plumbing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I eliminate the “whooshing” sound of water running though pipes?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2068/how-do-i-eliminate-the-whooshing-sound-of-water-running-though-pipes)

Good morning, just a quick question for you, if you can help me?
Just recently there is a surging sound through out the house when "any" water is turned on, what could this be?  The sounds stops as soon as the water is turned off.
As a side note, the city water people came and replaced my water meter in the front yard, could this have anything to do with this "new" sound?
Thank you, for any insight you can allow me.
Sincerly,
Miss M

Comment: Also [opening water pipe/tap has hissing noise throughout the house](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7676)