# How can I mitigate plumbing noise in a shared condo wall?

Tags: sound-proofing

We live in a condo and when the neighbors turn on their water is like the flood gates of hell. Is there anything I can do to block the sound.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/2072/46271.

Comment: Find the main water shut off for the neighbor's condo and turn it off. :D Snark aside, the link @Kris posted does look like it could be your solution. Either in your condo or your neighbor's. Ask one neighbor to come over to your place and have another person turn the water on in their place so they know what's happening, then go on a valve hunt to ensure they're all wide open.

Answer (score 1):

Small diameter pipes can be noisy, but fitting larger pipes while the « solution » now can be difficult and expensive.

Usually happens when a small pipe feed an area which then has a change of use and the water demand increases which increases the speed in the small pipe.

Usually on domestic pipes the speed should be kept below 2 m/s while hydraulic systems can be up to 7m/s.

Comment: This is a great explanation of the cause of the sound, but it doesn't really help answer "what can be done about this"...

Comment: @FreeMan fit a larger pipe... also warned that it can be difficult and expensive. Has to be better than turning off the supply to the neighbor's condo...

Comment: Fair enough, but not likely going to happen on the neighbor's plumbing, but possible.